# Make "question ban" help page specific to Maths.SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center, post-ban

The page in the Help Center concerning question bans ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)) was specifically written for StackOverflow.

Since then, Maths.SE has grown fast enough for this feature to be enabled here ([as of August 2013](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10717/43351)).

Due to some meta browsing, I encountered this page, and I noticed that particularly some of the referenced question-writing guides are strongly geared towards StackOverflow. As such, they contain advice such as "Provide sample code", which is useless for Maths.SE.

Considering that we have devoted quite a lot of effort to writing the ["How to ask a good question?" thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351), I think it's good to at least include that one in the list. While in the process of changing this, I would also suggest to cull the guides written specifically for StackOverflow.

Comment: [According to Shog9](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10717/quality-blocks-enabled-for-questions#comment40374_10717) that page is moderator-editable.

Comment: The page itself does not appear to be SO-centric. It seems we need people to write new support documents. Feel free :-)

Comment: @robjohn Unfortunately, I hate blogs. Let my contributions to the referenced meta thread suffice. But others should feel free, of course.

Comment: Nowadays, users should be hitting [rolling question limits](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) instead of the hard question ban, so it's this page that might need customization. @robjohn: is [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) mod-editable?

Comment: @Woodface No, that one doesn't have an "edit" link.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's a shame because "ask a good question" link would fit perfectly there (the text is there already, only the link needs to be changed). And the screenshot from SO could be replaced by a local one. I could post a feature request, or you could ping someone to make the page editable; let me know what works better.

Comment: @DanielFischer For now, I [added this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251102/259867) to another one I posted earlier on Meta, since they are about the same page.

Comment: @Woodface I can see if I can grab a CM to ask whether it's customisable or network-global.

Comment: @Woodface: We could customize that page per site, but since the rolling ban is active on all sites, it would be more efficient to fix the page for everyone. I've changed the word "code" to "details". Does that work?

Comment: @JonEricson Sorry about the confusion, but we are talking about two different pages here. Lord_Farin brought up "code" on the *outright question block* page (this block is also active here on Math); then I began to look at the page about rolling question limits. My main concern is that "our advice on how to ask good questions" on [rolling question limit page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) does not link to [very detailed advice](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/147263) specific to this site.

Comment: @Woodface Now (thanks to Pops) we have a link there. We still have the screenshot from SO, but meh.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for following up on this. I think we can live with the SQL injection thing. The advice to look at top-voted questions isn't particularly great either, but fortunately there's little chance that anyone will read it.

Comment: As Daniel pointed out, I've already made a slight edit to include a link to your community-generated "how to ask a good question" page. If you want more substantial changes, please make a more specific proposal (maybe as an answer). I'd be happy to replace the image, too, if someone who's handy with an image editor wants to basically recreate what's already there with a Math SE screenshot as the base image.